Gitlab CI/CD Access Restriction
I need to customize all repositories in my Gitlab instance:

Limit the number of allowed pipeline runs for a project (commit trigger and other) per day. So that it is not possible to abuse the resource time of the runner.
Restrict the ability of users to edit the gitlab-ci.yml file.


Regarding the first question, I looked up CI/CD limits and found Maximum number of pipeline schedules, however this limit does not take into account pipelines created on commit (logical from the name).

On the second question, I had an idea to move the gitlab-ci.yml file to another repository with less access. And use it in the current repository with include. In this case it will not be possible to make changes in the main gitlab-ci.yml file, but it will be possible to add or correct the one in the repository.



Пользователь, который работает с репозиторием и требует ограничения - Developer.

